# Error 19 when hidding parent element

Tags: highcharts

Please check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UnVrf/)

Just click on the test button and I'm having the error 19. This wasn't happening in highcharts 2.xx

The error happen here:

```
if ((axis.max - axis.min) / axis.tickInterval > 2 * axis.len) {
            error(19, true);
        }
```

It happens also with latest version from here: http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your click event just hides the chart div and then tries to resize the window (which might not even work in jsFiddle). Doing only one or the other does not throw the error. So it seems the combo of doing those two things together is problematic. But what are they doing?

Comment: This error happen in my application. What I just did was extract the portion of the code that combined causes the same error that happen in my application. I've created a demo in jsfiddle but if you want you can create a basic html page that reproduces the error.

Comment: From what I've saw in highcharts code in the reflow function (that is where the error starts) the code is not validating if the element is visible, and in my opinion if the chart is not visible there is no need to execute the code. This code is just needed only when the chart is visible.

Comment: Got it. This sounds like a bug to me. You might want to report it. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues

Comment: The problem is solved: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2273